# Thread safe lazy in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, mutex, lazy-evaluation

I am thinking of thread safe lazy, i.e., when forcing, we need to make sure the process is thread safe.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
type 'a t = 
  | Delayed of (unit -> 'a)
  | Value of 'a
  | Exn of exn

type 'a lazy_t = Mutex.t * ('a t ref)

let lazy_of_value x = Mutex.create(), ref (Value x)

let lazy_of_fun f = Mutex.create(), ref (Delayed f)

let force (m, t) = 
  Mutex.lock m;
  let x =
    match !t with
      | Value v -> v 
      | Exn e -> Mutex.unlock m; raise e
      | Delayed f -> 
    try
      let v = f () in
      t := Value v;
      v
    with e -> t := Exn e; Mutex.unlock m; raise e
  in 
  Mutex.unlock m;
  x
```

Basically, I attached a lock with a lazy type to be a new lazy type.

I wrapped the whole force process inside lock / unlock, but am I doing the correct thing?

Or I just need to lock / unlock when dealing with the case of `Delayed`?

I have this question because I think the `force` will only write / modify the lazy once when dealing with `Delayed`, but may have lots of read once it is determined. So if I wrap the whole process, it will be thread-safe for sure, but will have bad performance for the constant lock unlock. Am I right?

Comment: You could also have 2 levels of laziness, with one in the delayed function: thus you could include the mutex in the function itself, garanteeing any concurrent thread would stop there if the value is already being calculated, and the one you already have, without the mutex. The function would update both the inner and the outer refs.

Comment: @didierc yes, I deleted it

Comment: @didierc http://ideone.com/RYRGGn how about now?

Comment: The compilation works on my machine, I just don't have a test case for it.

Comment: anyway, I didn't know ideone supported ocaml (even if it's an old version).

Comment: btw, I seem to remember that you did some Java before starting to learn OCaml. Are you familiar with the threading techniques in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted in the comments, you could use a second layer of laziness in the evaluation in the the delayed function:

```
type 'a t = 
  | Delayed of (unit -> 'a)
  | Value of 'a
  | Exn of exn

type 'a lazy_t = 'a t ref

let lazy_of_value x = ref (Value x)

let lazy_of_fun f =
  let m = Mutex.create () in 
  let v = lazy (f ()) in
  let rec r = ref (Delayed (fun () -> 
    Mutex.lock m;
    try
      let v = Lazy.force v in 
      r := Value v;
      Mutex.unlock m;
      v
    with e -> r := Exn e; Mutex.unlock m; raise e
  ))
  in r

let force t = 
  let x =
    match !t with
      | Value v -> v 
      | Exn e -> raise e
      | Delayed f -> f ()
  in 
  x
```

Note that the mutex is completely eliminated from the outer `ref` value.

From your comment:

> What if someone wants to read while it is doing `f()`?

Two possibilities:

1. the outer ref has been already updated, and the newcomer just sees a `Value`, so no problem.
2. the outer ref is still a `Delayed`, which means the new thread will try to execute `f`. If another thread wants to a `Delayed` while it's already being executed, it will stop on the `lock`, and when it will proceed, the inner `lazy` will be forced already. On the other hand, if a thread comes along after the outer ref has been updated, it only sees a `Value`, and thus *doesn't have to go through the mutex locking mechanism*. The only possible problem I can foresee is if a second assignment to the outer `ref` with `Value v`<sup>1</sup> will actually lead to a different physical value being set in the `ref`, thus breaking any possible further physical comparison, but I don't think it may happens (we'll need a guru to confirm that).

Edit: 
Here's an implementation without using `Lazy.t`.

```
type 'a t = 
  | Delayed of (unit -> 'a)
  | Value of 'a
  | Exn of exn

type 'a lazy_t = 'a t ref

type 'a inner = 'a t ref

let lazy_of_value x = ref (Value x)

let lazy_of_fun f =
  let m = Mutex.create () in 
  let v = ref (Delayed f) in
  let rec r = ref (Delayed (fun () -> 
    Mutex.lock m;
    try
      let v' =
        match !v with
          (* first evaluation *) 
          | Delayed f ->f ()
          (* other concurrent evaluations *)
          | Value v -> v 
          | Exn e -> raise e
      in
      v := Value v';
      r := Value v';
      Mutex.unlock m;
      v'
    with e -> r := Exn e; Mutex.unlock m; raise e
  ))
  in r

let force t = 
  let x =
    match !t with
      | Value v -> v 
      | Exn e -> raise e
      | Delayed f -> f ()
  in 
  x
```

Caveat: both untested code.

---

<sup>(1): which will happens in case at least two threads run the delayed function concurrently.</sup>

Comment: What if someone wants to read while it is doing f()? I think the read should wait?

Comment: No, you are right. this is not a common read/write context. anyway, the real f() will be executed only once and only when first call to force. I think you are correct.

Comment: However, I don't want to really use system defined lazy or lazy.force. But I believe your idea should be correct

Comment: Do you think you can produce a new version without using Lazy.force or lazy keyword?